# set date and time in jquery datetimepicker based on another datetimepicker

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui-datepicker, jquerydatetimepicker

It works properly until any postback of control fired but when any postback event of control fire and then if we change "from date" than in "to date" datetimepicker it only shows date instead of date&time. same when I change "to date" than in "from date" datetimepicker it only shows date instead of date&time.it looks like it reset datetimepicker onClose(); 
I have also tried to set minDateTime and maxDateTime property but still, issue does not resolve.I am using **jqueryUI datetimepicker**

Issue_FromDate
[image: Issue_FromDate]

Issue_ToDate
[image: Issue_ToDate]

Code:

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>Demo</title> 
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>   
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon/1.6.3/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.min.js"></script> 
  <script>
  var server_date_time;
        function validation() {     
            var maxDate = $(".todate-with-time").val();
            var maxTime = maxDate.substr(maxDate.indexOf(" ") + 1, maxDate.length)
            if (maxDate == null || maxDate == undefined || maxDate == "") {
                maxDate = server_date_time;
                maxTime = moment(server_date_time).format("HH:mm:ss A");
            }

            var minDate = $(".frmdate-with-time").val();
            var minTime = minDate.substr(minDate.indexOf(" ") + 1, minDate.length)
            if (minDate == null || minDate == undefined || minDate == "") {
                minDate = server_date_time;;
                minTime = moment(server_date_time).format("HH:mm:ss A");
            }


            $(".frmdate-with-time").datetimepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                currentText: 'Today',
                showButtonPanel: true,
                timeFormat: 'hh:mm:ss TT',
                maxDate: maxDate,
                maxTime: maxTime,
                controlType: 'select',
                //onSelect: function (selectedDateTime) {
                //    this.fireEvent && this.fireEvent('onchange') || $(this).change();
                //    $('.todate-with-time').datetimepicker('option', 'minDate', selectedDateTime);
                //    //$('.todate-with-time').datetimepicker('option', 'minDate', $('.frmdate-with-time').datetimepicker('getDate'));
                //    //$(".todate-with-time").datetimepicker("option", "minTime", selected.substr(selected.indexOf(" ") + 1, selected.length));
                //}
            });
            $(".todate-with-time").datetimepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                currentText: 'Today',
                showButtonPanel: true,
                timeFormat: 'hh:mm:ss TT',
                minDate: minDate,
                minTime: minTime,
                controlType: 'select',
                //onSelect: function (selectedDateTime) {
                //    this.fireEvent && this.fireEvent('onchange') || $(this).change();
                //    //$(".frmdate-with-time").datetimepicker("option", "maxDateTime", selected);
                //    $('.frmdate-with-time').datetimepicker('option', 'maxDate', selectedDateTime);

                //}
            });
        }

        $(function () {
            server_date_time = new Date();    
            validation();           
            $(".frmdate-with-time").datepicker("setDate", server_date_time);
            $(".todate-with-time").datepicker("setDate", server_date_time);

            <!-- $(".frmdate-with-time").on("dp.change", function (e) { -->
                <!-- $('.todate-with-time').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date); -->
            <!-- }); -->

            <!-- $(".todate-with-time").on("dp.change", function (e) { -->
                <!-- $('.frmdate-with-time').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date); -->
            <!-- }); -->
        }); 

  </script>

 </head>
 <body>
 <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <span id="Label2" class="innerlabels col-sm-4">From</span>
                                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                                        <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                                            <input name="txt_FDate" type="text" id="txt_FDate" class="frmdate-with-time hasDatepicker" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss" readonly="readonly">                                            
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <span id="Label6" class="innerlabels col-sm-4">To</span>
                                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                                        <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                                            <input name="txt_TDate" type="text" id="txt_TDate" class="todate-with-time hasDatepicker" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss" readonly="readonly">                                            
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: one is datepicker and another is datetimepicker?

Comment: both are datetimepicker

Comment: can you make a fiddle?

Comment: it works properly until postback of control fire but when postback fire it behaves anonymously.

Comment: if postback issue can you check what is returned format of date ?

Comment: validate your date which is returning from server .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do that using below setting. use **dp.change** method

```
$(function() {
   $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
   $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
      useCurrent: false
   });

   $("#datetimepicker1").on("dp.change", function(e) {
      $('#datetimepicker2').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
   });

   $("#datetimepicker2").on("dp.change", function(e) {
      $('#datetimepicker1').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date);
   });
});
```

see working [example](https://jsfiddle.net/Negirox/1ruhoxby/)

Comment: it is working properly for Bootstrap datetimepicker but same thing can we implement for jqueryUI datetimepicker?

Comment: @user3629270 i think you need to show me which date picker you are using probably mak a fiddle

Comment: I am using jqueryui-datepicker  https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range

Comment: @user3629270 its a datepicker not a datetime picker

Comment: we can use timepicker using timepicker add-on